# How To Build Android SDK Project With Library Project Dependency With Maven

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I wants to build android project with Maven.

I have two projects

**Project 1 :** Master ( This is SDK project , this is not .APK )

**Project 2 :** Child ( library project )

How to add dependency of **Project 2** in **Project 1** ?

When I build **Project 1** with `mvn package` then I wants **.rar** file with **Project 2** included as a library project in **Project 1**.

Can you please suggest maven pom.xml code stuff for same.

If maven is not suited for this requirement then please suggest alternative solution if any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [Android Maven Plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/) in such cases.

Apart from that you should change your structure like that:

```
 +-- root (pom.xml)
      +--- master (pom.xml)
      +--- child (pom.xml)
```

So master can have a simple dependency on child and you can call it from the root.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is suitable for any standard or non-standard packaging.  If I had to build some non-standard package with Maven I would try with the Assembly plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Or in the worst case, some antrun in the package phase that would prepare whatever I need.  However, this is just an orientation, I have no real experience packaging Android apps and maybe you can find a much better specific solution for the case.

Comment: Thanks, Let me to check ref. link

Comment: A coworker just told me that now the standard solution is a Gradle packaging under Android Studio, which happens to be some IntelliJ IDE.  Probably that will give you the best tools avaliable.